# How to change the folder where socket.io is fetching the socket.io.js JavaScript file?

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io

The statement

> ```
> <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
> ```

looks for socket.io.js in the 'public' folder instead of node_module.

Changing the url to `../node_module/socket.io/socket.io.js` does not work.

How do I change the default folder which `src` looks into?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

socketio sever when receives the request '/socket.io/socket.io.js' , it dynamically builds the content ( considering the transports configured to be supported by the server ).

The file is neither served from public / node modules.